# Function to parameter tuple for decode

Tags: solidity, abi

I have an interface with a defined function:

```
interface IERC20 {
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
}
```

Does solidity have a way of specifying the function's parameters as tuple to pass to `abi.decode` so that we don't need to manually transcribe the parameters tuple?

Instead of

```
(address spender, uint256 amount) = abi.decode(data[4:], (address spender, uint256 amount));
```

I want this

```
(address spender, uint256 amount) = abi.decode(data[4:], IERC20.approve);
```